# sunspot solr sort using model field "score"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new in ROR. Sunspot solr search giving me headache.
I am sorting with field "score" and it is belongs to the child table and   It's not giving the result. 
I have verified the solr query and it appending data type with the field name

> float => _f ,  string => _s and Integer => _i
>
> Eg: field model  Age =  **sort: "age_f desc"**
>
> But for score it is coming like **sort: "score desc"**

Yes I understood "score" is some keyword in solr. But I have to use "score" as my field name as well..

Please any one help me for it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solutions for it. We have to add alias_attribute in model.

> alias_attribute :searchable_score, :score

Comment: I'm also having this problem, but alias attribute didn't help me, maybe I'm missing something?